# Rasa Protobuf TypeError

Tags: typeerror, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am working on a rasa chatbot and have created dependency issues. I tried downloading googleapi, and related google api services google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials, googleapiclient.discovery import build,cfrom googleapiclient.errors import HttpError, from google.auth.transport.requests

In this process I changed some dependencies and now my rasa_sdk fails and I get this error:
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

Downgrading the protobuf package fails because Rasa needs a higher version I have tried downgrading rasa, and removing the googleapis but it is still presenting this error when I try and train my model. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried removing googleapis, downgrading protobuf, downgrading rasa.